# Properties of optimization problem (convex, linear?)

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I have a set of optimization problems whose core is described as follows:

$A_{n\times q}.W_{q\times 1}=R$

$\sum_{1}^q w_i=1$

$w_i\geq 0, i=1...q$

where $A$ is given. We need to determine the $W$.
The optimization problems could be minimizing the sum of R (i.e. $\min(\sum_1^n r_i)$) or maximizing the minimum element, i.e. $\max(minimum(r_i)_{i=1...n})$.

I'm looking for the properties of these problems, including linearity, convexity, etc. And if a Conjugate Gradient method or ILP solvers could be helpful.

Comment: What are those $n\times q\cdot$ subscripts? Does the case of $W$/$w$ matter? You say only $w$ needs to be changed; does this make the objective constant?

Comment: @LinAlg I'm not sure if I got your question. But just to clarify: $n\times q$ shows the dimensions of vectors.
As we change $W$, $R$ would change and we need to optimize the minimum element of $R$ or the sum of its elements.

Comment: In that case my answer below answers your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be a linear optimization (LO) problem. For the objective of minimizing the elements that's obvious, for maximizing the minimum, the formulation is given by:
$$
\begin{align}
\max_{z,w,r} \quad & z \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & Aw=r \\
& w^T e = 1 \\
& z \leq r_i \\
& w \geq 0
\end{align}
$$
Free LO solvers like Clp or GLPK can solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The question may have been a bit misleading. I don't want to actually use a LO solver, but I want to implement it my self, preferably using iterative methods. So I'm looking for the properties that can help for that.

Comment: what's wrong with a LO solver? Especially since you mention ILP solvers.

Comment: I want to put it on a microcontroller, and have some trade-off too.

Comment: what are the dimensions of this problem? and how fast should it be solved? what trade-off are you talking about?

Comment: $n$ is not large. just about 10-15. But $q$ can be an order of magnitude larger.

The trade-off is compromising the optimality for a faster solution.

Comment: Try a compact linear optimization solver; fast and guaranteed optimal.